# displaying a div with the username of a friend in the friendlist when click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i don't know how to go about this,am building a chat system so what i want now is to display a div with the username of a friend when the friend name is click,like that of facebook and i want the name of the user to have a link to the id,so i can use it to identify which user echo's the message type inside the div,please someone should fix my code it's a mess right now.

this code display's my friend_list

```
 $list = "select friend_uid,friend_id from friend where user_id='$id' AND status='1'";
             $friend = mysqli_query($conn,$list);
             while($rowf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friend)){
                echo $rowf['friend_uid'].'<br>';

             }
              $friend_list = "select user_uid,user_id from friend where friend_id='$id'  AND  status='1'";
             $res_friend = mysqli_query($conn,$friend_list);

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_friend)){
               ?>
           <nav id="chat_id" onclick="view()"><a href="#chat<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['user_uid'].'<br>';}?></a></nav>
           <input type="text" placeholder="search for a friend">
       </div>
    </div>
    <?php


}?>
```

this the div which a want to display with the friend username when friend name is click

```
< div class="friend_chat">
           <div id="chat" style="display:none;">
           <label><?php echo $row['user_uid'];?></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="type a message">
              <?php

              ?>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <script>

              function view(){
              var chat = document.getElementById('chat');
              if(chat.style.display = "none"){

              chat.style.display = "block";
              }else{
              chat.style.display = "none";
              }
              }
              </script>
```

Comment: but this code is not working it only display the div without any username

Comment: Is `$row` populated at that <div> point in your script? For example, if you do `<?php print '$row values: "' . print_r($row, true) . '"'; ?>`, does it show that the variable blank?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the userid of user via url and get it on the chat div if your not using ajax:

```
   <a href=
   "chat.php?uid=
   <?php echo 
    $row["user_uid
    "]; ?>"><?php 
    echo 
    $row["userna
    me"]; ?></a>
```

then on the chat page do:

```
  <?php
   if(isset($_GET["
   uid
   "])){
   echo '<div 
   class=
   "chat">'.$_GET[
   "ui
   d"].'</div>';
   }
  ?>
```